# I am trying to test useSelector and UseDispatch hooks using jest , How i can do that

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TQMC.png)

```
function Finaltable() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState({ loading: true });
  const [curIndex, SetcurIndex] = useState(1);

  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [scanAPIdata, setScanData] = useState([]);
  /*istanbul ignore next*/
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let [scanCount, setScanCount] = useState([]);
  //dispatch({type: 'fetchdata'}),
  /*istanbul ignore next*/
  const account_id = useSelector(state => state.app.user ? state.app.user.crm_account_id : '');

  let pagination = GetPager(scanCount, curIndex, perPage);

  let SortData = getCookie("SortScan");
  const defaultsort = [
    {
      "field": "name",
      "direction": "ascending",
      id: "Profile Name", desc: "false"
    }
  ];
  const status = () => { return SortData === undefined || SortData.length === 0 ? defaultsort : JSON.parse(SortData); };
  const [sort, setSort] = useState(status);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: sagaActions.FETCH_DATA_SAGA });


    let finalData = {
      account_id: account_id,
      range: {
        start: pagination.startIndex,
        end: pagination.endIndex
      },
      order: sort
    };

    postScanListAPI(finalData).then((res) => {
      setScanCount(res.headers["total-count"]);

      setScanData(res);
      setLoading({ loading: false });
    });`enter code here`
  }, [sort, account_id]);
```

I am writing test code for this but getting errors on mocking useDispatch and useSelector using jest.

const account_id = useSelector(state => state.app.user ? state.app.user.crm_account_id : '');

const dispatch = useDispatch();

How i can write test code for both above lines.

Answer (score 0):

Mock your whole redux for the selector. Mock the dispatch globally with jest.fn()

Comment: can you please share the test case for mocking, actually don't have much knowledge of mocking of useDispatch and useSelector